# How to get rid of a smell that has permeated the walls of a dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher, smell, plastic

The other day, we ran a load of dishes in our dishwasher and one of the containers had been holding a particularly fragrant spice in it. After the load was done, we found that the dishwasher itself now smells strongly like the spice.

We've run numerous cycles with things like borax, vinegar, and baking soda to try to remove the smell and while it has diminished a bit, it still smells pretty strongly like the spice. It's like the smell has permeated the plastic walls itself.

Is there a way to remove the smell from the dishwasher? It's literally brand new (less than a month old) so we would really like to save it if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: If the interior walls are white plastic then there is nothing wrong with spraying some bleach based cleaner on them.

Comment: Most dishwasher detergents contain bleach, so to some extent that has been done, though of course a stronger solution could be applied. If the smell is not being retransmitted to items washed, just give it time, it will go away.